# Floating Div is not working

Tags: html, css, jsp, css-float, jsp-tags

I am trying to add floating div tag which contains delete buttion. Its not working.
I am using struts1.X and tiles.

My web page build with 3 jsps: Menu.jsp, Body.jsp, Fotter.jsp. I am tring to add new floating delete buttion.

My CSS file,  In my CSS I have added 2 floating styles.

```
div.floatingBtn {
  width: 350px
  position: fixed;
  top: 90%;
  left: 34%;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  }

div.flating {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
  paddding: 2px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px
  z-index:100;
}
```

My body.jsp:

```
<div class="flating"><table align="center"><tr><td>
<button id="DELETE" class="btn" onclick="deleteDocs();" >Delete</button></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

I tried with both styles, but they don't work. Why?

Comment: most likely your button does not have a class of `floatingBtn`, otherwise the `position: fixed;` may not be supported by your browser.

Comment: I have given my floatingBtn style to my DIV tag. I am using ie8,

Comment: try to change your css `div.floatingBtn` to `#DELETE` to make the reference. According to http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed `postion:fixed` should work on ie8

Answer (score 0):

The first CSS doesn't have any effect in your html, because your HTML doesn't contain anything in CSS-Class "floatingBtn".

Second, your CSS hasn't any `float:` rules. This is because you don't get any floating elements.

If you want fixed positioning - which is a very different thing as float! -, you had to set also its position (add a `left:` and `top:` to the `div.flating` rule as well).

Comment: I tried to with "floatingBtn" also. its not working.I have added left top to flating its not working.

Comment: @sarmachinta It had to. You have probably some other problem as well. Show a jsfiddle.